# How to model transition probability if action does not lead to a state change (in MDP)?

Tags: markov-process, markov-decision-process

An MDP (markov decision process) is defined as a set of states $S$, actions space $A$, Transition Probabilities $T$ and Rewards $R$. An action $a$ in a state $s$ usually result in a change of state and the probability is defined as $p(s'|s,a)$. I have a question if an action $a$ in a state $s$ does not result in a change of state then how to define transition probabilities $p(s'|s)$? How to define state transitions from $s$ to $s'$ when state transitions do not occur after taking an action $a$ in a state $s$?

Answer (score 1):

You could always have a transition function which all the states transition back to themselves with probability 1:

$$P(s' = U | s = V, a) = \mathbf{1}(U = V)$$